# How can i create ReactRouter Default Route

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, backend, web-frontend, react-fullstack

As i want to navigate my dashboard component by default when user sign with its credentials. So how can i make the dashboard component default and how can i change it with the sideNav here are the example of my project the user navigate to dashboard and it is showing blank [image]

and when i click on the sidebar component it is rendering the component so how can i make dashboard as default using function component
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello Abbas, have you tried just using <Route path="/" ...> ?

Comment: yaah but in this case i want the default route as /Dashboard as of my / path is for startuppage

Comment: Ok, so if I understood correctly, you basically want to redirect users to the dashboard based on some condition, right? (redirect from '/' to '/Dashboard')